# Why is my sender() DeadLetters from a scheduled message?

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to schedule a message to be sent after a period of time - a simple retry.

```
override def receive = {
  case Worked => ???
  case DidNotWork => 
    val target = sender() // Avoid closing over sender().
    import context._
    context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(500.milliseconds, target, TryAgain)
}
```

This works as expected, however, when I receive the `TryAgain` message, and access `sender()` to try and get this `ActorRef` to this object, I get `DeadLetters`. Why is this happening?

(Note that the problem is the `sender()` call in the other actor, which is not in a closure - this is not a problem where I'm closing over `sender()`):

```
override def receive = {
  case TryOnce => sender() ! DidNotWork
  case TryAgain => sender() ! Worked // sender() here is DeadLetters!
}
```

Complete example (in response to [cmbaxter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958369/why-is-my-sender-deadletters-from-a-scheduled-message/24958370#comment38800597_24958370)):

```
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem, Actor}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sys = ActorSystem("Test")
    val test = sys.actorOf(Props[Test], "test-actor")
    test ! "badtest"
    test ! "goodtest"
  }
}

class Test extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case "badtest" =>
      import context._
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.milliseconds, this.self, "bad")
    case "goodtest" =>
      import context.dispatcher
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.milliseconds, this.self, "good")
    case other => println(s"$sender $other")
  }
}
```

Which produces:

```
Actor[akka://Test/deadLetters] bad
Actor[akka://Test/user/test-actor#621986067] good
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because of the `import context._` call. This line is causing an ambiguity in resolving the `implicit ActorRef` required by the `scheduleOnce()` function to get the sender.

The `ActorRef` `self` exists twice - once in the `Actor` (as it normally is), and once in the function scope, from the `import` from `context`. This results in the implicit not finding `self`, and as `tell()` defaults to `DeadLetters`, this results in the problem you have.

If you note [the example usage of `import context._` in the Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#actor-api), it is done at instance-level, not function level. This means `self` replaces the `Actor`'s default value instead of shadowing it, removing the ambiguity.

Other options are to import only `context.dispatcher` to make the `scheduleOnce()` call work, or pass it explicitly.

```
import context._ // Option 1

override def receive = {
  case Worked => ???
  case DidNotWork => 
    val target = sender() // Avoid closing over sender().
    //import context.dispatcher // Option 2
    context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(500.milliseconds, target, TryAgain)
    //context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(500.milliseconds, target, TryAgain)(context.dispatcher) // Option 3
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your answer here.  The only two things that are tied to an `ActorContext` that are implicit and thus are in scope after importing `context._` are the dispatcher and the `ActorSystem` the actor lives in.  I don't think you are getting ambiguity on the implicit `sender` from `scheduleOnce`.  There is an implicit `sender:ActorRef` arg on `scheduleOnce`, but it has a default value of `Actor.noSender` and that is why you are seeing deadletters.  If you had an implicit `ActorRef` in scope, it would  work just fine

Comment: I am inside an Actor - [there is an implicit `ActorRef` in scope - `self`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.4/#akka.actor.Actor). This works when I don't do the `import context._`. When I try to access `self` after the `import context._` call, I get `Error:(18, 7) reference to self is ambiguous;
it is both defined in trait Actor and imported subsequently by  import context._` - so I'm pretty sure I'm right on the cause of this, but if you know better, please do explain why the implicit provided by the `Actor` isn't working.

Comment: You are right that the `self` in the `ActorContext` is not `implicit`, but that doesn't seem to matter. I've edited my question to include a complete example that shows the issue at hand. You can see quite clearly that the `import` of `context._` is what causes the implicit to fail.

Answer (score 0):

So in digging in more, I agree that the import of `context._` is the issue.  There is a `self` on `ActorContext`, but it is not implicit.  When you import it into scope, it supplants the implicit `self` that comes with every `Actor`.  So now you have a `self` ref in scope but it's no longer implicit and that's why you see a deadletter there.  If you have situations like this in the future, and you want to fully import context because you can easily fix the issue by moving the scheduling to a separate method in the actor like so:

```
class Test extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case "badtest" =>
      import context._
      scheduleFromMe("bad")
    case "goodtest" =>
      import context.dispatcher
      scheduleFromMe("good")
    case other => println(s"$sender $other")
  }

  def scheduleFromMe(s:String)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext) = context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.milliseconds, this.self, s)
}
```

Removing the `ActorRef` from the implicit params for this new method allows the call to the scheduler to always pick up the implicit self `ActorRef` that is this actor.