# Receiving reply from routees

Tags: c#, akka.net

I have an actor that creates a ScatterGatherFirstCompleted router and sends a message to get some data. This is just a simple example I made to try out different routers. 
When the reply is received, the sender of the reply is DeadLetters. I expected that the sender would be one of the actors managed by the pool router.
I'm curious why is this, and if I'm doing anything wrong?

EDIT:
In accordance with acarlsteins comment, I'm adding some code.
So here is the parent actor that is created in the actor system, a child of the /user guardian actor:

```
public class TailChoppingActor : ReceiveActor
{
    private static void SendTCMessages(string message, IActorRef router)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);

        router.Tell(new Request("Sadržaj... bla bla bla", new Random()));
    }
    public TailChoppingActor(IActorRef collector)
    {
        Receive<Go>(x =>
        {
            var within = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            var interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            var props = Props.Create(() => new MyActor(collector))
                .WithRouter(new TailChoppingPool(5, within, interval)); 
            var childRouter = Context.ActorOf(props);
            SendTCMessages("TailChopping", childRouter);
        });
        // Context.Sender is DeadLetters
        Receive<Reply>(x => Console.WriteLine($"Got reply from: ${x.Sender} (Akka sender: {Sender})"));
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the child actor:

```
public class MyActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public MyActor(IActorRef collector)
    {            
        Receive<Request>(x =>
        {
            var self = Self.Path.ToString();
            var wait = x.Rnd.Next(0, 2000);
            var millis = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(wait);
            Console.WriteLine($"{self} got message: {x.Content}, waiting: {millis} ms");
            Thread.Sleep(millis);
            Sender.Tell(new Reply(x.Content, self));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advice to add some code into your question. I will increase the chances of getting help plus reduce the chances of having your question flagged and closed.

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958369/why-is-my-sender-deadletters-from-a-scheduled-message